# Multiple Magento Installation with PVT and SHARED Products DB

Tags: multi-vendor

Is it possible to share a Products DB between multiple Magento stores?

Comment: Between multiple stores? or between multiple Magento instances? Magento supports multiple websites on the same instance. See this: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/overview-how-multiple-websites-stores-work. If you want to share the same database between multiple instances...you'll have to wait for an answer because I don't know. But please make your question clear.

Comment: Multiple Magento Instances

Answer (score 2):

Separate Magento instances - not natively, you could de-couple the product model from Magento itself, to allow for a common DB where some properties are not set. But it would take an exhaustive amount of time and defeat the entire multi-store architecture of Magento.

You can have multiple stores on a single installation.